# Roblox Studio - Warning/Error when i try to sell the "snow" in my backpack

Tags: lua, roblox

As you can see on the picture below I can't sell what I have in my backpack when I enter the circle. I get this error/warning and I can't figure out what the problem is. I have found out that the problem happens on line 5: `player:WaitForChild`

The Error/Warning on line 5: Infinite yield possible on  `Players.asbjornbonde.PlayerGui:WaitForChild("Stats")`

Here is the picture:
  [image: Screenshot]

Here is my code:

```
script.Parent.Touched:connect(function(Hit)
    local player = game.Players:FindFirstChild(Hit.Parent.Name)
    if player then
        local leaderstats = player:FindFirstChild("leaderstats")
        local PlayerGui = player:WaitForChild("PlayerGui"):WaitForChild("Stats").Backpack
        if leaderstats and PlayerGui then
            local Cash = leaderstats:FindFirstChild("Cash")
            local snow = PlayerGui:FindFirstChild("snow")
            if Cash and snow then
                if snow.Value <= 0 then
                else
                Cash.Value = Cash.Value + 2 * snow.Value
                snow.Value = 0
                script.Parent.DigSound:Play()
                script.Disabled = true
                wait(0.1)
                script.Disabled = false
                end
            end
        end
    end
end)
```

I have used many hours on trying to fix this problem but i really can't. I would appreciate help.

Answer (score 3):

`Infinite yield possible on` is a warning in Roblox Studio that means there is a possibility that your script could be stuck on that line waiting forever if object it is waiting on doesn't exist and is never created.

As the only `WaitForChild` that is causing an error is two `WaitForChild`'s joined together I'm guessing the script doesn't like you doing that.

### First Solution

If you were to split both `WaitForChild`'s into two different variables it shouldn't give you the error however this is creating another variable for no real reason so I would go for the second solution.

### Second Solution

As the player has loaded in and touched the part it's safe to assume the GUI has loaded for them so you can change your `WaitForChild` to `FindFirstChild` if you still want to check you didn't get a `nil` or you can reference it normally: `player.PlayerGui.Stats.Backpack`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can't find out why Stats is missing. i have tried almost all day.

Comment: @AsbjørnBonde Here's a different way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Think of `WaitForChild()` as a loop. It is constantly executing in the background, as fast as the Lua engine can execute it. Wouldn't recommend using this or any sort of un controlled loop in Roblox Lua as the engine doesn't handle it very well.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a server script with a filtering enabled game, the issue is that the server cannot access existing members of PlayerGui. To work around this, you either need to run this code on the client (with the necessary changes), or you'll need to make use of a remote event!